# apache web server - URL should serve contents from the web server but url/path should take it to backend server

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, webserver, proxypass

I'm able to do both of these separately but not with the same settings though. I've an apache web server in front of an app server. If I access the web server URL , `http://<URL>/` it should serve contents from the web server. However if I access `http://<URL>/path/` it should redirect to the backend app server.

proxypass, proxypassreverse is working if I use "/" . If I use /path, it isn't. There is no reference for the path in the web server except for some rewrite rule am trying to set `RewriteRule ^/abc http://APPURL/` Any help is appreciated. Am still learning a lot.. Thanks.

```
ProxyPass / http://APPURL/
ProxyPassReverse / http://APPURL/
```

Comment: `ProxyPass /` means reverse proxy *everything* to specified backend, so if it is not working for you, you are landing somewhere else and that directive is not being applied.

Comment: If I use /abc in proxypath, it's not working. It still takes me to backend server and fails .